# Microsoft Powerapps gallery is not showing any text

Tags: mobile-application, powerapps

I am trying to put a simple gallery on my app that is connected to excel through OneDrive. However, the connection can find the table in my spreadsheet but for some reason nothing is showing up.

[image: This is my table]

[image: Nothing is showing up]

As you can see, The table data is not there. When hovering over the table name in the formula, it says PowerApps didn't find any data. But there is very clearly data in the table.

Comment: Ensure `Gallery2`'s `Items` property is set to the correct table name. Click each of the labels in the gallery and ensure their `Default` property is set to `ThisItem.Name` and `ThisItem.Seat` accordingly.

Comment: @SeaDude yes they are

Comment: Ok someway somehow I left my screen for a few minutes and when I came back the data was in the gallery. I'm not going to bother figuring out why

Answer (score 1):

In future refresh your data source in Power Apps Studio. It will start to display after that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me using SharePoint as data source, and it  wasn't data refresh issue. I've attempted to insert gallery in component, and it won't work. It worked in a separate non-component screen.

Answer (score -1):

Big shock / same problem.  The card IS in the gallery, but none of the data is visible on the card.  I can click on the card and get the ThisItem data returned to a field / variable, so I know it's all there.  Appears to be an issue with components in PowerApps in-tandem with the gallery control.

As a result, I decided to add a timer and it *appears* as if it may have fixed the issue.  Am allowing one second between the population of the dataset that fuels the parameter that fuels the component's gallery and resetting of the form.

Anyone else just LOVE Microsoft quality products?